# how to create a amazon cloud machine using ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to the amazon world.

I have got an amazon ec2 machine with it's public dns and a .pem file . i have connected to the machine using putty by generating a ppk file . now i am able to login to the remote machine using root user. Can someone help me how to create a remote desktop machine or as a cloud machine  like the way windows has a rdp feature so that i can install the software. Do i need to install vncserver on it ?. if yes, is there any handy video or documentation which can provide me steps to connect . i have to install appache 2 and mysql on it.

Appreciate your help.

P.S. I can't see any instance on the amzon ec2 which can be created with the machine dns i have got.

Thanks.

Comment: after login with putty, you can install apache2 and mysql directly, why need remote desktop things?

Answer (score 0):

1) To see you instance in AWS Console, you need to choose region, where that ec2 server is deployed.
Click on right top menu, there is list of regions there.

2) As we understood, you need to install LAMP Server on that instance.
There are lots of examples how to do it (without GUI, using command line interface).
Find them easily typing how to setup lamp server on ubuntu/centos, depending on your OS.